# Break up Large Row Heights with React Virtualized?

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm planning on rendering a list that contains nested tables.

If, for example, a row happens to contain a table containing 100s of items, would react-virtualized break up that row? Or would it render the entire row no matter its height, therefore defeating the purpose of virtualized infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is a no:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/980